# Suitability of Naive Bayes classifier in Mahout to classifying websites

Tags: bayesian, mahout, classification

I'm currently working on a project that requires a database categorising websites (e.g. cnn.com = news). We only require broad classifications - we don't need every single URL classified individually. We're talking to the usual vendors of such databases, but most quotes we've had back are quite expensive and often they impose annoying requirements - like having to use their SDKs to query the database.

In the meantime, I've also been exploring the possibility of building such a database myself. I realise that this is not a 5 minute job, so I'm doing plenty of research.

From reading various papers on the subject, it seems a Naive Bayes classifier is generally the standard approach for doing this. However, many of the papers suggest enhancements to improve its accuracy in web classification - typically by making use of other contextual information, such as hyperlinks, header tags, multi-word phrases, the URL, word frequency and so on.

I've been experimenting with Mahout's Naive Bayes classifier against the 20 Newsgroup test dataset, and I can see its applicability to website classification, but I'm concerned about its accuracy for my use case.

Is anyone aware of the feasibility of extending the Bayes classifier in Mahout to take into account additional attributes? Any pointers as to where to start would be much appreciated.

Alternatively, if I'm barking up entirely the wrong tree please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You can control the input about as much as you'd like. In the end the input is just a feature vector. The feature vector's features can be words, or bigrams -- but they can also be whatever you want. So, yes, you can inject new features by modifying the input as you like.

How best to weave in those features is another topic entirely -- there's not one best way to convert them to numbers. [Mahout in Action](http://manning.com/owen) covers this reasonably well FWIW.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that book mentioned previously, I may give it a shot.

If I understand your response correctly, you're saying that I could manipulate the input to handle extra features by creating some encoding for them. e.g. a hyperlink body may be handled as a-body-[encoded-string].

What is still unclear to me is how I would tell the classifier to weight certain input features differently to others.

Any further guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: In the end it is a number in a vector. Yes, that's one way to leverage the tokenizer to get there. Ask at user@mahout.apache.org, it's a good question and the original author can tell you more.